# Git checkout while leaving new files

Tags: git

I am wondering if there is a way for me to do a git checkout that replaces every file in the file system with what is in the branch - but leaves any new files, that were never committed, as is?

I believe

```
git checkout --hard
```

will wipe the file tree entirely and replace it with what is in the branch, and the other options will leave local changes or ask me to stash them.

Comment: What does "leaves any new files, that were never committed, as is" mean?  If they're new and never committed, they're not part of either checkout, and git won't overwrite them, but presumably you're asking because git surprised you by deleting something -- that would surprise me, too, usually git is so careful not to delete things it irritates and confuses newcomers, the complete reverse of what seems must be your situation here. So, more detail, please?

Comment: You are right - I lost a bunch of changes which I thought were never a part of any commit. Maybe I should got through git log and confirm.

Comment: The one command that will cause git to delete untracked content is `git clean`, which is how you tell git to delete anything git doesn't care about.  It makes the `clean` and `distclean` make targets really really easy to write :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
git reset --hard
```

which will overwrite modified tracked file with the last committed version.  Untracked files will not be modified.

Comment: Do you know what the specific difference is between this and git checkout --hard is? In terms of what happens in the file system?

Comment: I just did a "git help checkout" and don't see --hard as an option.  There is a "git checkout --force" which will checkout your working tree to a given commit's state, even if the index or working tree is different from that commit.  In other words it throws away changes, but to *tracked* files.